# Short story where bird-like aliens land on destroyed Earth

Tags: story-identification

I’m looking for a short story about bird-like aliens who land on Earth. The human race have died in a battle with other aliens, and we had no choice but to destroy our sun.

At the end of the story it becomes clear the the aliens are some kind of birds, when you read the story you think it is about humans landing on an other planet.

Who wrote it and what is it called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An old and old fashioned story that is similar to your description is "The Dead Planet" (1946) by Edmund "World Wrecker" Hamilton.

A list of where it has been published is here:

[https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?69069[1]](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?69069%5B1%5D)

It was first Published in *Startling Stories*, Volume 12, # 1, Spring, 1946.

[https://mega.nz/#!OQBlVYZB!oy5z-1avqYDhMzWl4mhiEXM_10-WaG75nsXS-PzmBEU[2]](https://mega.nz/#!OQBlVYZB!oy5z-1avqYDhMzWl4mhiEXM_10-WaG75nsXS-PzmBEU%5B2%5D)

Comment: The story is available for free at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Startling_Stories_v13n03_1946-Spring#page/n83/mode/2up).

Comment: The part about destroying our sun: “So we determined that, before we perished, we would destroy them. They were creatures of force who could only be destroyed by force. We converted our sun into a gigantic generator, hurling some of our planets and moons into it to cause the cataclysm we desired. From our sun generator sprang a colossal wave of force that swept out and annihilated the photon race in one cosmic surge of energy."

Comment: The ending, where we learn that the viewpoint characters are avians: We looked at each other, we three tall bird-men of Rigel, as Dril handed us the glasses of pink sanqua. On Tham’s beaked face, in his green eyes, was an expression that told me we all were thinking of the same thing. He raised the glass that he held in his talons. "To that great dead race to whom our galaxy owes all," he said. “We will drink to their world by their own name for it. We will drink to Earth."

Comment: Many many thanks to the OP who answerd my question.

Comment: Many Many thanks tonthe OP who answerd my question greetingd from The Neatherlands